# Post Google Plus Stream

Tags: google-plus

Any idea about how to post on our Google+ Stream using javascript or json?
I'm not searching how to use the google+ button, I need to post on the wall(or stream)

Answer (score 5):

The (recently announced) Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Here's some information to help you get started.

http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2011/09/getting-started-on-google-api.html
http://developers.google.com/+/

Answer (score 3):

These two urls do what you want, but need a confirmation from the user:

- `https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=YOUR_TEXT`
- `https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL_HERE`

Comment: how do I add some pre-filled text (i.e. I want to fill in some text, by default, in the post)

Answer (score 2):

No public API is available, so just register for the private API and check for yourself

https://services.google.com/fb/forms/plusdevelopers/

**EDIT: The API is available now:
https://developers.google.com/+/**

Answer (score 1):

That's the downside of the Google Plus...
See here: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41